# Connecting Android to Mysql using java

Tags: java, android, mysql

My question is how to connect android with java,and Mysql? I am doing a project on android  where i need to save the data given by the user in database. can anyone help me in this?

Comment: better way is through web server

Comment: The database at the server or in android???? I hope at server as you saying MySQL

Comment: If it is local android data storage , It is "SQLite" not MySQL.. Look at this sample example here https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: Why do you want to connect android to MySQL. in Android you should use API to send data to server and then  server side code should take care of this.

On android saving data into Sqlite  is best thing to do

Comment: If it is php with mySQL then look here https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: If you need to use remote MySQL database, create web service using that database and access this service from your mobile application.

Answer (score 0):

I would generally expect JDBC to work on Android against MySQL.  I am sure you can find plenty of good examples there and make it work if this is really what you want.  However there are a few things you want to make sure of before you go this route:

1. Is your app connecting directly to a database server?
2. Is that expected to be available through a firewall?
3. Are you sure you won't need something like connection pooling?

I could imagine cases where one might want to connect directly to a database server from Android but these are niche cases.  Make sure it is what you want to do and then use the relevant JDBC driver if it is.